# Google cloud function finishes with status ok even when I return 500 error code

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using python for a google cloud function.
When an exception occures I catch it and reutrn error code 500 but the log shows that the funcion finishes with status "OK".
This is the code:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import datetime
import traceback
from variables import *
import json
import time

def main(event, context):

    pubsub_headers = event['attributes']
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    product_data = json.loads(pubsub_message)

    try:
      raise Exception()
   except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
        return "ERROR", 500
    finally:
        time.sleep(30)
```

The log message is:
"`Function execution took 30014 ms, finished with status: 'ok'` "
If I raise an exception in the main function without catching it, the finished status is "crash"

Comment: Where is the #CODE ??? without the code how you expect us to debug ??? atleast mention pseudo code so people can understand what is happening

Comment: I can't post all the code, there are too many files.

Comment: That's why i mentioned ```Pseudo Code```.

Comment: The problem is not the core code, if I raise an exception it will be caught but will end with status "OK"

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting a **"`Function execution took 30014 ms, finished with status: 'ok'`"** is because:

- The [`finally`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_finally.asp) block is always executed regardless if the code raised an error or not. The code `time.sleep(30)` results in the function execution taking 30014ms
- The `status: 'ok'` is generated in the logs because it corresponds to the function's overall execution. Even though you raised an exception, you caught it which results in the function's successful execution.
- The `status: 'crash'` is generated in the logs because you raised an exception without catching it. The function encountered it which results the function to crash.
- The `return "ERROR", 500` simply returns a [tuple](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-returns-multiple-values-how-to-return-a-tuple-list-dictionary/#:%7E:text=lists%2C%20and%20dictionaries.-,Tuples,-A%20tuple%20is) that contains a string "ERROR" and an integer "500".

To get your expected result, take a look at **[Reporting runtime function errors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting)**. Here you can handle and report runtime errors that occur in the Cloud Functions.

There is a recommended way for a function to signal an error depending on the function's type:

- **[HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions)** - should return appropriate HTTP status codes along with the denoted error.
- **Event-driven Functions** - should log and return an error message. See [Background Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions) and CloudEvent Functions for more information.